# What is the meaning of t="shared" in a formula element?

Tags: openxml, xlsx

When inspecting a cell element in XLSX file, I find the following formula element:

```
<f t="shared" si="0"/>
```

What is the meaning of such a formula element?

Answer (score 14):

[ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) Part 1 Section 18.3.1.40 says:

> The possible values for the t attribute are defined by the simple type ST_CellFormulaType, and are as follows:

```
...
shared (Shared formula)
...
```

> Shared formula. If a cell contains the same formula as another cell, the "shared" value
>   can be used for the `t` attribute and the `si` attribute can be used to refer to the cell
>   containing the formula. Two formulas are considered to be the same when their
>   respective representations in R1C1-reference notation, are the same.

Basically it is a space saving optimisation. One that is guaranteed to be a pain for anyone parsing/modifying the file.

Comment: _"If a cell contains the same formula as another cell, the "shared" value can be used"_ is not completely true, [only certain kinds of formulas work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54654993/1026).