# Open XML Excel some formulas are not supported by shared formula

Tags: .net, excel, openxml

Excel doesn't support the shared formulas (created by the OpenXML SDK https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) as expected:

- formulas having a reference to a sheet and not using absolute references (eg. “=VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet2!A:B;2;0)”)
- formulas using structured references such as [@[Sales Amount]] (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

provoke errors when the file is opened or saved, sometimes with the following error: "one or more formula ... are longer than the allowed limit of 8192 characters"

On the other hand, the following shared formulas work correctly:

- “=VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet2!$A:$B;2;0)” (using absolute references with dollars).
- "=A1" or "=$A1" (when extending the formula across a column)

The XML structure looks like this:

```
B2: <c r="B2"><f t="shared" ref="B2:B3" si="0">VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)</f><v></v></c>
B3: <c r="B3"><f t="shared" si="0"></f><v></v></c>
```

Replace the formula by the one with dollars, it will work. By a structured references, it won't, etc.

When using such formulas through the Excel UI, expanding the formula will either lead to a shared formula or not, depending on whether the formula is supported (I suppose). Trouble is that all formulas should be supported, or else it should be documented somewhere.

---

> When a formula is a shared formula (t value is shared) then this value
>   indicates the group to which this particular cell's formula belongs.
>   The first formula in a group of shared formulas is saved in the f
>   element. This is considered the 'master' formula cell. Subsequent
>   cells sharing this formula need not have the formula written in their
>   f element. Instead, the attribute si value for a particular cell is
>   used to figure what the formula expression should be based on the
>   cell's relative location to the master formula cell.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellformula.aspx

As anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

After long talks with Microsoft support, their answer is:

> First of all, even though we clearly understand it would be easier to
>   have Shared Formulas, it is not how Excel works.  Excel itself does
>   not create the shared formulas that you are trying to create. If you
>   enter the same formulas in Excel, fill down and save, you get the
>   repetitive formulas stored and not the Shared Formulas.

(This is true, but Excel also creates shared formula when they work, my issue here is that not all formulas work.)

> The error is clear that Excel will not work with it, which is
>   consistent across all versions of Excel from 2007 and higher.  In this
>   case, as a workaround, you should mimic Excel and replicate the
>   formulas down the sheet as Excel does which works without errors.

And how am I suppose to know beforehand if the formula will be supported by Excel?
Microsoft doesn't even propose an official library to parse Excel formula. We could use https://github.com/spreadsheetlab/XLParser that looks pretty solid, but the whole point of using shared formula is not to parse the formulas, and let Excel do it.

> The only way this behavior can be altered is to implement a design change
>   into Excel’s behavior but by doing so the whole backwards
>   compatibility will be broken all the way back to the 2007 version.
>   This is not something our Product Group is interested in changing.

So Excel will keep crashing when saving the file with weird error messages...

> As I was verifying internally to better answer your questions I now
>   have a clear confirmation from my Escalation Team that the discussion
>   about details in the file format handling, or in-memory handling in
>   Excel of said shared formulas won’t change the outcome. Matter of
>   fact, there are scenarios where one cannot use shared formulas for
>   many different reasons, some of them might not be apparent and visible
>   from outside Excel. The best rule of thumb is the one already
>   outlined: don’t use shared formulas when Excel itself doesn’t use one.
>   And this needs to take things into account like subtle differences in
>   the formulas, whether there are absolute or relative references (as in
>   the your example with A:B vs $A:$B), whether the reference refers to
>   the same worksheet or another one, or in a different workbook, etc.,
>   then also what kind of formula it is used in (some functions like
>   OFFSET or INDIRECT have dependencies on ranges that are subject to
>   change during a calculation), and whether precedent or dependent
>   ranges/formulas indicate that it might be safer to not use shared
>   formulas. The file format documentation doesn’t clearly state under
>   what conditions a shared formula can be used. It specifies that a file
>   reader could encounter such formulas, and when this happens how to
>   handle that, but that doesn’t mean that shared formulas are always
>   possible or encouraged whenever a contiguous range of cells contains
>   the same formula in the formula bar. For a file writer, it isn’t
>   encouraged to use unless the scenario is restricted to exactly the
>   same as when Excel writes a shared formula.

Still, LibreOffice handles it perfectly. Looks like "it's too complicated to fix" or "it's too risky to fix the bug" excuse.

Since they suggested that I create a User Voice entry, you can vote for it there:

https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/37328965-full-support-for-shared-formula-matching-the-open

Comment: Well that's disappointing. "Though we clearly understand it would be easier to have Shared Formulas, it is not how Excel works." Yes, it is. See ECMA-376 5th ed. section 18.3.1.40 on formulas: specifically the "si" attribute (page 1632): "When a formula is a shared formula ... then this value indicates the 
group to which this particular cell's formula belongs."