# Excel XLSX XML files: where is the formula?

Tags: excel, xml

After unzipping the .XLSX file, I see in worksheet7.xml:

```
<row r="10" spans="1:86" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
...
<c r="AU10" s="1794"><f t="shared" si="13"/><v>2022</v></c>
...
</row>
```

I looked in the `sharedStrings.xml` file, but the 13th string is not my formula. I am wondering: where I can find the formula for this cell?

I think this is relevant:

```
<row r="10" spans="1:86" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
  ...
  <c r="AN10" s="469"><f t="shared" ref="AN10:BE10" si="13">AM10+1</f><v>2015</v></c>
  ...
  <c r="AU10" s="1794"><f t="shared" si="13"/><v>2022</v></c>
  ...
</row>
```

I am still not sure what the algorithm could be to get the correct formula for cell AU10.

PS. Julia's XLSX package is not handling this correctly. It returns an empty formula for the cell AU10.

Answer (score -1):

Formulas are stored in `[sheetname].xml` ( folder: \xl\worksheets\ ) with tag `<f>`.

[image]

---

`si` stands for Shared Group Index. In my example, cells B2:B6 have the same (shared) formula pattern `A[row]+A[row+1]+100` rather than all pointing to B2's specific formula. The cell references change based on the row. And B4,B5,B6 are not included in xml at all. I guess key indicator seems to be `ref="B2:B6"`.

Please refer to Microsfot document:

> [CellFormula Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k20e.png)

[image]

I'm not an expert on it. You may have a look this post:

[Open XML Excel some formulas are not supported by shared formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654993/open-xml-excel-some-formulas-are-not-supported-by-shared-formula)

Comment: Most of the time. Not in this case. See the t tag in my xml file. Excel has saved this differently.

Comment: Shared formula is a big topic. I have updated my post.